# Get value to the left in pivot table in Qlik

Tags: pivot-table, qliksense

Is there a way to get the percentage of a value to its left in a pivot table?

[cohort analysis table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyfrN.png)

For example, instead of the value 40 in Month May-22 i would like to show 54% instead ( % of 74) but the value 74 need to be shown as a full value of 74. Same with Jun-22, I would like to show 44% instead of 83 which is the percentage from 187.

Is this possible?

I've tried using set analysis for this but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
=Sum(Expression1) & If(Not IsNull( Before(Sum(Expression1)) ), ' (' & Num(Sum(Expression1) / Before(Sum(Expression1)), '#,##0%') & ')')
```

...where `Expression1` is your measure value.

This works by checking to see if the cell to the left is null and, if it's not, then putting the percentage in parentheses.

This is what I get (using randomly generated numbers):

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense table results]